# Idle in transaction and lock with PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, transactions

I have a query that is locked. Thus my web application is locked and I don't really understand why.

Looking at the PgAdmin I have this :

[image: Activities]

If I understand correctly, the orange query has been blocked by the query just above (which is in "idle in transaction" state).

Does it mean that the "idle in transaction" transaction is not committed ?
And is it because it is not committed that the other transaction is locked ?

If I commit the "idle in transaction" transaction, will it unlock the locked transaction ?

To be honest I don't really understand how I should interpret this. Can you help me ?

Answer (score 3):

Yor assumptions are correct. "idle in transaction" means the session (in this case PID=16686) started a transaction and is holding some locks on the `goodscontract` table.

Note that the select that you see for PID=16686 is most probably not the statement that is blocking the update (writers are not blocked by readers in Postgres). It is highly likely that PID=16686 ran a different statement previously that acquired the lock (or the select contains a `for update` clause - as your screenshot doesn't show the full statement this is impossible to tell).

In general it is highly recommended to end a transactions as soon as possible (using `commit` or `rollback`) - that includes read-only transactions that only do `select`s.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Actually I'm using Play Framwork (which uses Hibernate). As far as I know, play frameworks opens a transaction at the beginning of an HTTP request and commits it at the end. But in my case the blocked transaction is a stateless transaction I manually opened. Also, your right, in the idle transaction there was a previous update request on the goodscontract table. All of this means that I should manually handle transactions to commit them before I open my stateless transaction ?

Answer (score -1):

two things need to be updated on postgresql.conf

idle_transaction_timeout

shared_memory

will solve the problem.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).